# Write extern await result into database in c# .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await

I have an external source which gives me the current geolocation for a given IP which I want to add into my database.

```
UserSession newSession = new UserSession()
{
    UserId = userId,
    Value = sessionValue,
    ValidUntil = duration,
    Browser = browser,
    Device = device,
    Engine = engine,
    Ip = ip,
    Region = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.City),
    Postal = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.Postal),
    Country = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.CountryName),
    LoginDate = DateTime.Now
};

db.UserSessions.Add(newSession);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This doesn't work because the await isn't finish with processing, so its value is null. I've tried something like this which resolves the same result.

```
async Task FillSessionInformation(IpDataClient client, string ip, int sessionId /* id of saved session */) {
    using (dbContext db = new dbContext ()) {
        UserSession session = db.UserSessions.Where(x => x.Id == sessionId).FirstOrDefault();

        session.Region = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.City);
        session.Postal = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.Postal);
        session.Country = await client.Lookup(ip, x => x.CountryName);

       /* its always the same request so it should be possible to create a variable */

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

// await Task.Run(() => {
//     FillSessionInformation(client, ip, sessionId);
// });

await FillSessionInformation(client, ip, sessionId);
```

Based on the given information, how can I solve this problem? I'm not very familiar with Task- or async-Functions in c#.

Comment: Have you tried to perform the client.Lookup calls without a database update? Just purely the external geo info retrieval calls. Do they return the expected values?

Comment: The `db.UserSessions.Add` line will not execute until the tasks returned by the three `Lookup` calls have completed. Unless you're doing something very odd within that method, the properties will only be `null` if the `Lookup` task returns `null`.

Comment: Richard is correct. @RoyBlunk, please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've made some testing and it's true. If I'm on local machine the external source does not return something, thats why nothing is written. Thank you very much for the hint, I've figured out a solution for my problem. @RichardDeeming

Comment: Geolocation postal codes are rarely correct. You're often lucky to get the right country.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the helpfull comment of Richard I figured out a working solution.

```
var client = new IpDataClient(IPDataClientKey);

UserSession newSession = new UserSession()
{
    UserId = userId,
    Value = sessionValue,
    ValidUntil = duration,
    Browser = browser,
    Device = device,
    Engine = engine,
    Ip = ip,
    LoginDate = DateTime.Now
 };

 if (ip != "::1" && ip != "127.0.0.1")
 {
     var lookup = await client.Lookup(ip);

     newSession.Region = lookup.Region;
     newSession.Postal = lookup.Postal;
     newSession.Country = lookup.CountryCode;
  }

  db.UserSessions.Add(newSession);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

The main problem was the external source which gave me unexpected results. The problem got triggerd by my local machine ip.